# A question about norm for bounded linear transformations

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $H$, $K$ be Banach spaces, and let $A: H \rightarrow K$ be a
bounded linear transformation.
Its norm is defined by:
\begin{equation}
\|A\| = sup\{\|Ah\|_K: \|h\|_H \le 1\}
\end{equation}
How to prove that $sup\{\|Ah\|_K: \|h\|_H \le 1\}$ is equivalent to:
\begin{equation}
sup\{\|Ah\|_K: \|h\|_H = 1\}
\end{equation}
Many thanks in advance,

-- 
Cesar

Comment: one of the directions is trivial; for another direction, consider $y=\frac{1}{\left \| h \right \|}h$.

Comment: Thanks, I already considered that option, but how to prove that the supremums are the same?

Comment: I wonder if we can claim this: If $A=B$ then $sup(A)=sup(B)$. I hope others can help here as well.

Comment: Note that the equivalency does not hold in the trivial case $H = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume $h^*$  maximizes (supremizes) $\|Ah\|_K$ and $\|h^*\|_H<1$, Then you can find scalar $\alpha$ such that:

$$\|h^*{'}\|_H=\|\alpha h^*\|_H=\alpha\|h^*\|_H=1$$

Since $\|h^*\|_H<1$, we should have $\alpha=\frac{1}{\|h^*\|_H}>1$ in order to hold the equality, therefore:

$$\|Ah^*{'}\|_K=\|A(\alpha h^*)\|_K=\alpha\|A h^*\|_K\geq \|Ah^*\|_K$$

Therefore, for any solution $h$ where $\|h\|<1$, there exist a solution $h{'}$ where $\|h{'}\|=1$, where the value of $\|Ah{'}\|_K$ is no less than the value of $\|Ah\|_K$.

As a result $h^*$ should have been equal to $h^*{'}$ in the first place, because the $\sup$  operator would return the larger value among the plausible ones.

Comment: This does not work if $H = \{0\}$.

Comment: @grew: I think the norm should be homogeneous and convex, I don't understand your comment. :) what is the analytic form of the norm in that case?